# Netbeans conditional Field Breakpoint - check on new assigned value

Tags: java, netbeans

Can I set a field breakpoint on that stops on field modification checking the new assigned value in Netbeans?

In my example i want the breakpoint to hit at line 14 when x is assigned the new value 5.

[image: Netbeans Breakpoint Dialog]